# JavaScript - loosing the context while using 'setTimeout'

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am writing a script for changing the background while iterating through the elements ( after each change its getting back to default ), but I can't get the `setTimeout` to work

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  window.onload = Main.init();
});

var Main = {       
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  *       
  init: function() {   
    $('#button').click( this.chBackground );    
  },
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  *        
  chBackground: function() {
    $('#r1 > div').each( function() {
      $(this).css('background', 'white');
        setTimeout( this.backPrevious , 800);
        //if( this.id == 'b3') return false;
      })
    },        
  backPrevious: function() {      
    $(this).css('background', 'whitesmoke');
  },
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  *
}
```

So the code inside `chBackground` function gets run, but than it's not getting back to default ( backPrevious ). I was reading about loosing the context of this keyword, but either way can't figure it out.

Comment: Your Javascript is invalid. Did you mean to set all those as properties of `Main`?

Comment: Oh my, what a formatting, anyway, this will not even compile since you are defining methods of an object outside of an object.

Comment: That closing bracket was wrongly pasted, it's not there. Pardon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to use `arrow function` that doesn't have its own `this`, so the calling context is not switched. Therefore you don't have to bind `this`.

```
setTimeout(() => { this.backPrevious(); }, 800);
```

Edited version:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   window.onload = Main.init();
});

var Main = {
   init: function() {
     $('#button').click( this.chBackground.bind(this) );
   },
   backPrevious: function(elem) {
     $(elem).css('background', 'whitesmoke');
   },
   chBackground: function() {
     const elems = document.querySelectorAll('#r1 > div');
     for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
       elems[i].style.background = 'white';
       setTimeout(() => this.backPrevious(elems[i]), 800);
     }
   }
}
```

The problem was that `click` function in the `init` bounded its own `this` pointing to the `button` instead to the `main`. So you have to keep the correct binding there by using `.bind(this)` and then you have to pass each element as an argument to the `backPrevious` function.

Comment: That just declares the function, you also need to execute it.

Comment: Ofc, I have just blindly copied the text. Should be ok now.

Comment: unluckily it's not..  it's throwing `TypeError: this.backPrevious is not a function`,  have tried with self also, same.

Comment: @linearSpin This works for me. Can you create a working example, here or in fiddle, so that we can debug it?

Comment: button in top-left triggers the function, and the boxes get white, while after every iteration-step the previous should get back to default color

Comment: @Matus Dubrava Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
setTimeout( this.backPrevious.bind(this) , 800);
```

But you are losing context in `each` function too, so do it like this:

```
chBackground        : function() {
    var self = this;
    $('#r1 > div').each( function() {

        $(this).css('background', 'white');
        setTimeout( self.backPrevious.bind(self) , 800);

        //if( this.id == 'b3') return false;
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried but I'm getting `self.backPrevious is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is actually `window.setTimeout`. So, the calling context of anything called inside of `setTimeout` will be the `window` object. You need to specify that the `this` value of `backPrevious` when you call it refers to the element in the collection you're iterating over in `chBackground`.

Easiest to use arrow functions to avoid `this` confusion:

```
chBackground: function() {
  $('#r1 > div').each((_, div) => {
    $(this).css('background', 'white');
    setTimeout(() => this.backPrevious.bind(div), 800);
  })
},
```

Comment: `this.backPrevious is undefined`,

Comment: See edit - the Javascript is pretty weird because the `this` value inside of `backPrevious` has to be *different* from `Main`.